# SQL case sensitive string comparison with like and "="

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, string-comparison

i have one table named category.

in this table i have two columns 1.) `cat_id`, 2.) `cat_name`

in this table i have added record with this value : `cat_id` = `1`, `cat_name` = `test`

Now when i am going to run select query

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE cat_name = 'Test'
```

this query returns me null result because in database record string is **`test`** and in query it's a **`Test`** mark the differance of capital string here. Instade of null result i want the result with 1st record.

also i want same result in vice versa small and capital string.

i am using sqlite as database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use upper function.

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE upper(cat_name) = upper('Test')
```

Comment: great answer. it woks for both side case.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE cat_name = 'Test' COLLATE NOCASE;
```

Answer (score 1):

use LOWER:

`SELECT * FROM category WHERE LOWER(cat_name) = 'test'`

will get you all combinations of TeSt

Comment: what happen if my compared string like this **LOWER(cat_name) = 'TesT'** ?

Comment: Won't work.  Lower converts all chars in the string - cat_name - to their lower case version.  So if cat_name was 'TesT', then lower(cat_name) will still equate to 'test'.  But if you use the line I suggested you will still find cat_name if it equals 'TesT, coz you use a lower case string to compare with